# No puedo visualizar la vista previa en Xamarin.Forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto con xamarin en android studio pero no me permite visualizar la vista previa y me sale el siguiente mensaje de error.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya tengo actualizado xamarin.Forms

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error que te sale esta muy claro, debes actualizarte a la ultima versión de Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: he actualizado todos los paquetes de Nuget

Comment: `xamarin en android studio` ¿y si explicas por qué usas la etiqueta "Visual-Studio" ? por otro lado, ¿clean and rebuild?